# How to handle obsolete observable data

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-routing, observable

What should one do to handle obsolete data ? I have two similar (yet not exactly the same) scenarios. One when there is new data, and the other when there is no new data in Observable:

Case one :

1. User navigates to category say /laptops
2. User clicks on product
3. User wants to get back to categories but clicks on different category say /monitors

In code it looks like this :

```
export class CategoryComponent implements OnInit {

private category : Observable<Category>;

constructor(private categoryService : CategoryService , 
            private activatedRoute : ActivatedRoute){
    this.category = categoryService.category;
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.subscribeToUrlChange();

}

private subscribeToUrlChange(){
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params  =>{
        const category = '/'+params['category'];
        this.categoryService.getCategory(category);    

    });
}
```

}

What will happen here is view will render first and for the duration of http call say 200ms old category will be displayed, then quickly when http request resolves and new category hits category subject, view would refresh with information from "monitors" category.
I am assuming this annoying behavior would be even worse during peak hours in production. 
Easy fix would be to first send null to category subject and then perform http request, but this opens another set of problems.

Case Two:

```
export class CartComponent{

   private order : Observable<Order>;

   constructor(private cartService : CartService) {
      this.order=this.cartService.order;
   }
}
```

On the other hand cartService will have something like this :

```
private _order : Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
public order : Observable<Order> = this._order.asObservable();
```

Dilemma: When user logs out, should i just this.__order.next(null) ? Is there a more elegant way to handle this ?

Comment: If you want to display _"no data"_, you should set the state to _"no data"_ - and most often _"no data"_ is represented by _"null"_ or _"undefined"_ or an _"empty object"_

Comment: Yes for case two ,when there is no data, sending null or empty object seems reasonable. I asked because i thought there might be some rxjs feature for this common scenario, although i couldnt find any. But scenario one is what really bothers me.

Comment: It's the same case: It depends and what you want to display to the user while the request is active - there are so many ways to handle this, none of which are really rxjs-related but more a question of usability: If you want to display an empty page: null your data, if you want to display a loading-spinner: add some additional logic to display a spinner while a request is pending or: you could show a spinner, do the request and only move to the categories-route once the request is done... there are just so many possibilities